# Programmatically detect a redirected folder in Windows 7 and above

Tags: c#, .net, windows, directory

As an example of a redirected folder, I map the OneDrive folder to a non-OS, larger disk drive as follows using the `Move` button under location:

[image: Redirected OneDrive Folder]

The OneDrive settings still point to the old location but when it is opened in Windows Explorer, it takes you to the newly assigned location e.g. `F:\OneDrive`.

Is there a way to programmatically determine whether an arbitrary folder has been redirected and if yes, to where?

**EDIT**: Please note that this question is NOT about how to retrieve the OneDrive folder in the first place. It is about detecting redirection on any arbitrary folder.

Comment: This [information](http://superuser.com/a/728323) could be helpful. I can't verify it because i am on win 8.1

Comment: And if there is no API to detect this, you could just compare the current location  of OneDrive folder with the default location, which is `%userprofilefolder%\OneDrive`.

Comment: Arbitrary folders can't be redirected, only shell folders.  You can determine the current path for most (all?) shell folders with, e.g., SHGetKnownFolderPath, but presumably there is a .NET equivalent.  I don't think there is any function to tell you what the default path is, but presumably you don't really need to know whether or not the path has been changed, just what it is now.  (NB: the OneDrive folder might be implemented differently to the standard shell folders, I'm not sure.)

Comment: I *think* you should be able to determine the path for a shell folder by starting with SHGetDesktopFolder, e.g., http://www.gamedev.net/topic/126384-using-the-ishellfolder-interface/ (but I'm hazy on the details).  This might be more general than SHGetKnownFolderPath, e.g., it might work for the OneDrive folder.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: You should post your first comment as an answer.